# HTML/Javascript radio button forms that redirects to different links

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a radio button form where the selection would redirect you to a different index.html link when a Continue button is pressed. I cant seem to find an easy way to do this. Help!!

Basically as follows:

```
<form>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button1^" checked>this button goes to index1.html (Default)<BR></BR>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button2^">this button goes to index2.html<BR>   </BR>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button3^">this button goes to index3.html<BR>  </BR>
<input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bespoke service where you tell the community what you want and we develop code for you. Demonstrate that you have at least made an effort by showing the javascript code you've written so far and we'll help you sort out what's wrong.

Comment: I can not think of a business need with such a requirement. I would you 3 anchor tags to keep it clean and simple. Why do you want the use to make multiple clicks?

Answer (score 1):

In html add a data-href attribute for each button and ID to submit button

```
<form>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button1^" data-href="index1.html" checked>this button goes to index1.html (Default)<BR></BR>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button2^" data-href="index2.html">this button goes to index2.html<BR>   </BR>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button3^" data-href="index3.html">this button goes to index3.html<BR>  </BR>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" id="btnFormSubmit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var submit = document.getElementById('btnFormSubmit');
submit.addEventListener('click', submitForm);

function submitForm(event){
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

var href = '',
inputs = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
         if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') == 'button' && inputs[i].checked){
             href = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-href');
             window.location = href;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery will be like that, add the url to the value field of the radio.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="RADIO" name="button" value="index1.html" checked>this button goes to index1.html (Default)<BR>
    <input type="RADIO" name="button" value="index2.html">this button goes to index2.html<BR>         
    <input type="RADIO" name="button" value="index3.html">this button goes to index3.html<BR>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    });
});
```

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nnEny/

Answer (score 0):

This might be too obvious but

```
<form>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button1^" checked>this button goes to index1.html (Default)<BR></BR>
</form>
<form>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button2^">this button goes to index2.html<BR>   </BR>
</form>
<form>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="^button3^">this button goes to index3.html<BR>  </BR>
<input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Comment: This would not work. There is only one submit button but 3 forms

Comment: does anyone know if this is going to a page that collects this data? you could just create a redirect page that takes the data and redirects the browser